# What's the API to read database config details in elastic beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

AWS command line provides API to read elastic beanstalk environment information:

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-ids 'e-438kcmnae5'`

However, I didn't find documentation to read the detailed database configuration (as shown in the browser console below) from an API.

[image]

Comment: You can use SSM(AWS Parameter Store) in order to store the environment variables like this. Then you can securely access it and manage it with SSM and ElasticBenastalk without any additional complexity.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [`DescribeEnvironmentResources`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environment-resources.html) Beanstalk API:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources --environment-name <environment-name>
```

Result:

```
{
    "EnvironmentResources": {
        ...

        "Resources": [
            ...
            {
                "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
                "LogicalResourceId": "...",
                "PhysicalResourceId": "...",
                "Properties": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Endpoint",
                        "Value": "..."
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Port",
                    "Value": "3306"
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    ...
}
```